# Trying to get the count of shares of a post from Facebook wall using GraphAPI and Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am retrieving data from Facebook using the GraphAPI and python. For a post, given a post id, I can retrieve the total number of likes and comments. However, I cannot retrieve the total number of shares.

The query line on GraphAPI is

```
216311481960_10154125934861961?fields=shares,likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0)
```

Where 216311481960_10154125934861961 is the post_id(node in GraphAPI). 
This gives absolutely fine result in the GraphAPI interface.

`

```
{
  "shares": {
    "count": 723
  },
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 7750,
      "can_like": true,
      "has_liked": false
    }
  },
  "comments": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "order": "ranked",
      "total_count": 420,
      "can_comment": true
    }
  },
  "id": "216311481960_10154125934861961"
}
```

`

But when I am trying to access the same using a python code, I can access **likes** and **comments** edges, but cannot access **shares** edge. Trying to access it gives me the following problem.

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#100) Invalid edge (shares) on node type (Post)
```

How to access the number of shares of a post using python script?

Comment: You are likely using different access tokens in both cases, and/or making the request against different API versions. Go debug the tokens used to see which permissions they include in both cases.

Comment: I am using a single access token for all 3 cases. An access token that has all permissions enabled.

Comment: Must rather be a problem with your python then I suppose.

Comment: Have you tried anything similar and has it worked?